# Compiler error in dev c script

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, dev-c++

I try to write a script that the user inserts a username and a password and there are only two specific answers, username="movie" and password="mo".

The whole "login" process must be done in a function. So I wrote the following code and the compiler gets me those messages:

> "[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'login' makes integer from pointer without a cast" in mutiple lines...Also i got an error message in line 26.

Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
char login(char user,char pass);
int main(void)
{
    char user[5]="movie";
    char pass[2]="mo";
    login(user,pass);
    return 0;
}
char login(char user,char pass)//function login//
{
    printf("USERNAME:\n");
    scanf("%char",&user);
    if (strcmp(user,"movie")!=0)
    {   
        system("cls");
        do 
        {
            printf("Wrong username,try again.\n USERNAME:");
            scanf("%char",&user);
            system("cls");
            while (strcmp(user,"movie")!=0);
        }
    }
    printf("PASSWORD:\n");
    scanf("%char",&pass);
    if (strcmp(pass,"mo")!=0)
    {   
        system("cls");
        do 
        {
            printf("Wrong password,try again.\n PASSWORD:");
            scanf("%char",&pass);
            system("cls");
            while (strcmp(pass,"mo")!=0);
        }
    }
    return pass,user;
}
```

Comment: `char` is a *single* character. Also, C programs are not scripts.

Comment: Scan(℅char) is wrong to get. Use Scan(℅c)

Comment: What is `return pass,user;` supposed to do ?

Comment: Please define the `char` arrays to be much longer - even the initialisations do not allow enough room for the string terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: Comments such as `//function login//` are pointless.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the parameters "user" and "pass" to the `login` function ?

Comment: This code is terribly broken, please start with a smaller program and work your way up. Along with the problems listed in the comments above, you also have malformed do-while loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys.It's a task for my semester actually.I'll be correting and looking up the things you pointed out,and i'll let you know !!

Comment: @SumitGemini i used (%s) in the end..I think is the right choice because it's about a string, and not a single character,thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Konstantions . See if you try to print string by ℅s then don't use &. I suggested you to use ℅c because u r using & to get input.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's a task for my semester.I'm supposed to create a reservation system for a movie thater.So I analyzed the questions and tried to create small codes and compile them together in the end...So this post contains only the first question of the task! I want the "return pass user" to return the variables user, pass in main function (I will design the whole program in the following days)

Comment: @SumitGemini Ok thanks i'll try it!

Comment: @Tim This is only the first question of the task so I think that i cannot make it "simpler".But I think i messed up the nested loops.If I may ask, can i nest a "do...while" in an "if..else" ? Thanks!